# How do i get my x and y value to detect a collision between two images in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make two images collide (one is a cannonball called figBola and the other a ballon called figSprite), the problem I have is that I always get a value of 0 in both a.x, a.y and b.x, b.y when using alert(); in my colliding function when I am supposed to get the position of both images in that moment which equal x and y. Both of my images width and height are returned correctly. This is what I have tried so far (the colision code is at the bottom):

```
function iniciar(){

    elemento =  document.getElementById("area");
    lienzo = elemento.getContext("2d");
    figSprite = new Image();
    figSprite.src = "ballon.png";
    figBola = new Image();
    figBola.src = "bola.png";
    figCanon = new Image();
    figCanon.src = "cañon.png";

    //mostrar imagen en canvas
    dibujar_sprite(450,20);
    dibujar_bolita(50,20);
    dibujar_canon(0,20);
    incremento=true;

    xcanon = 0;
    ycanon = 20;
    inccanon = 0;
    inccanon1 = 2;
    //variables de posicion
    xs = 450;
    ys = 20;
    incy = 3;
    intervalo = 25; //miliseg, num veces = 1000/25 = 40
    //definicion del intervalo
    repeticion=undefined;
    xbolita = -50;
    ybolita = -20;
    incx=3;
    disparar=true;
    window.addEventListener("keypress", mover, false);
}

function animacion(){
    lienzo.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    if(incremento===true && ys < 430)
    {
        ys+=incy;
        dibujar_sprite(xs, ys);

        if(ys+incy > 430)
            incremento = false;
    }

    if(incremento===false && ys > 20)
    {
        ys-=incy;
        dibujar_sprite(xs, ys);

        if(ys-incy <= 20)
            incremento = true;
    }

    ycanon+= inccanon;

    if(ycanon < 20 || ycanon > 450)
    {
        inccanon=0;
    }

    xbolita+= incx;
    dibujar_bolita(xbolita, ybolita);
    dibujar_canon(xcanon, ycanon);

    collision(figSprite, figBola);
}

function btnStart_click(){
    repeticion = setInterval(animacion, intervalo);
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
}

function btnStop_click(){
    clearInterval(repeticion);
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
}

function btnUp_click(){
    inccanon = -2; 
}

function btnDown_click(){
    inccanon = +2;
}

function btnShoot_click(){
    xbolita = 20;
    ybolita = ycanon;
}
//draw images
function dibujar_sprite(x,y){
    lienzo.drawImage(figSprite, x, y);
}

function dibujar_bolita(x,y){
    lienzo.drawImage(figBola, x, y);
}

function dibujar_canon(x,y){
    lienzo.drawImage(figCanon, x, y);
}

function mover(e){
    valor = e.keyCode;

    if(valor === 38)
        ycanon -= inccanon1;

    if(valor === 40)
        ycanon += inccanon1;

    inccanon=0;
}
```

collision code where i am passing images as varibles:

```
function collision(a, b){
    if(a.x < b.x + b.width && a.x + a.width > b.x && a.y < b.y + b.height && a.y + a.height > b.y)
    {
        alert(a.x);
        alert(a.y);
        alert(b.x);
        alert(b.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone pls help?

Comment: Do I have to repost this for the third time?

Comment: Hi- in answer to your two comments, 1) When you post a question, it is implied that you are seeking help, so asking for help is redundant. and 2) No, if you have posted your question already, once will do.  When and if someone sees your question and has information that will help, they may do so.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's your problem: an `Image` object doesn't have `x` and `y` properties, but it does have `width` and `height`. Thus, when you try to access the `x` and `y` properties in your `collision` function, they come up as `undefined`.

It looks like you have the coordinates of each object stored in variables already (`xcanon`, `ycanon`, etc.), so those can be used as additional arguments in your `collision` function, however, this may not be your best bet. You *could* also define `x` and `y` properties of each `Image` object, however, I think a bit of refactoring is your best bet here. Try creating a custom JavaScript object for each item you're working with:

```
function GameItem (image, x, y, width, height) {
    this.image = image;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

var spriteImage = new Image();
spriteImage.src = "ballon.png";
sprite = new GameItem(spriteImage, 450, 20, spriteImage.width, spriteImage.height);

// etc.

// collision method now works between two of these objects:
collision(sprite, bola);
```

If you use this code, be sure to update your draw-- er... *dibujar* methods. :)

PS: Sorry, but my Spanish-JavaScript reading skills aren't in their prime.

Comment: Thank you :)! I was thinking that it was something about the image and I asked a similar question about collision with images but no one answered.